# Remove conditions in Where clause in a SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, regex, string

I have a requirement where I want to remove a condition in 'where' clause in a SQL query string.

This removal should work like this if my query is

```
Select * 
from table1 
where column1 = @c1 and column2 = 10
```

then after the removal it should be

```
Select * 
from table1 
where column2 = 10
```

and if my SQL query is

```
Select * 
from table1 
where column1 = @c1
```

then after the removal it should be

```
Select * 
from table1
```

What is the best way to do this in C#? I can use Regex or is there a better way?

Comment: Do it the other way; `where (column1 = @c1 or @c1 is null) and (column2 = 10)`.

Comment: so every time you want to remove `where column1 = @c1`?

Comment: If "yes" is the answer at @WhatsThePoint question: Is it always the first where statement when there are more then one?

Comment: Looks to me like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267497).  Perhaps it would be more effective if you describe your original problem.

Comment: Yes @WhatsThePoint

Comment: @MightyBadaboom It can be the first condition after the where keyword or might be after and/or etc but every time when there is a variable I have to remove that condition

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Not tried yet actually confused whether to use a regex or not ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest way, but this will do the trick in your case.

```
return query.Replace((query.IndexOf(" and ") != -1 ? "column1 = @c1 and " : " where column1 = @c1"), string.Empty);
```